# Sharing apk in android

Tags: android, apk

i am trying to share the apk with the help of a button, it was working fine until yesterday but now when i press the share apk button, the app crashes, i have no idea what is wrong with it but in run tab it shows something is wrong on the last line of below java code.

this is the java code

```
    btnShareApk.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = getApplicationContext ().getApplicationInfo ();
                    String apkPath = applicationInfo.sourceDir;
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent2.setType ("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent2.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile (new File (apkPath) ));
                    startActivity (Intent.createChooser (intent2,"Share Apk via"));
                }
            });
```

this is the xml code

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShareApk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_green"
            android:text="Share Apk"

            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

this is the log from run tab

```
    Process: com.faisalnazir.computerapplications, PID: 6184
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/app/com.faisalnazir.computerapplications-mLlY2QJaNLHfnA_i9z-hoQ%3D%3D/base.apk exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:2083)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2388)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:977)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10820)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10826)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10805)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1712)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5263)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5648)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5616)
        at com.faisalnazir.computerapplications.ShareActivity$2.onClick(ShareActivity.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7256)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7218)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27719)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to onCreate

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
builder.detectFileUriExposure();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copy apk file to your app cache folder, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile` to parse `File` to `Uri` .

Link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#GetUri

Answer (score 0):

You can share your app using intent. Like :

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(intent.ACTION_SEND);
```